# Using zmq::proxy with REQ/REP pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, zeromq

I'm trying to understand how the zmq::proxy works, but I'm encountering problems: I'd like to have messages routed to the right worker, but seems like the identity and the evelopes are ignored: in the example I would like to route messages from client1 to worker2, and messages from client2 to worker1, but seems like the messages are served on a "first available worker" based rule.
Am I doing something wrong, or did I misunderstood how the identity works?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <zmq_addon.hpp>

using namespace zmq;
std::atomic_bool running;
context_t context(4);
std::mutex mtx;

void client_func(std::string name, std::string target, std::string message)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    socket_t request_socket(context, socket_type::req);
    request_socket.connect("inproc://router");
    request_socket.setsockopt( ZMQ_IDENTITY, name.c_str(), name.size());

    while(running)
    {   
        multipart_t msg;
        msg.addstr(target);
        msg.addstr("");
        msg.addstr(message);

        std::cout << name << "sent a message: " << message << std::endl;
        msg.send(request_socket);
        multipart_t reply;
        if(reply.recv(request_socket))
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mtx);
            std::cout << name << " received a reply!" << std::endl;

            for(size_t i = 0 ; i < reply.size() ; i++)
            {
                std::string theData(static_cast<char*>(reply[i].data()),reply[i].size());
                std::cout << "Part " << i << ": " << theData << std::endl;
            }

        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }

    request_socket.close();
}


void worker_func(std::string name, std::string answer)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    socket_t response_socket(context, socket_type::rep);
    response_socket.connect("inproc://dealer");
    response_socket.setsockopt( ZMQ_IDENTITY, "resp", 4);

    while(running)
    {
        multipart_t request;

        if(request.recv(response_socket))
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mtx);

            std::cout << name << " received a request:" << std::endl;
            for(size_t i = 0 ; i < request.size() ; i++)
            {
                std::string theData(static_cast<char*>(request[i].data()),request[i].size());
                std::cout << "Part " << i << ": " << theData << std::endl;
            }

            std::string questioner(static_cast<char*>(request[0].data()),request[0].size());

            multipart_t msg;
            msg.addstr(questioner);
            msg.addstr("");
            msg.addstr(answer);

            msg.send(response_socket);
        }
    }

    response_socket.close();
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    running = true;

    zmq::socket_t dealer(context, zmq::socket_type::dealer);
    zmq::socket_t router(context, zmq::socket_type::router);
    dealer.bind("inproc://dealer");
    router.bind("inproc://router");

    std::thread client1(client_func, "Client1", "Worker2", "Ciao");
    std::thread client2(client_func, "Client2", "Worker1", "Hello");
    std::thread worker1(worker_func, "Worker1","World");
    std::thread worker2(worker_func, "Worker2","Mondo");

    zmq::proxy(dealer,router);

    dealer.close();
    router.close();

    if(client1.joinable())
        client1.join();

    if(client2.joinable())
        client2.join();

    if(worker1.joinable())
        worker1.join();

    if(worker2.joinable())
        worker2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-proxy):

> When the frontend is a ZMQ_ROUTER socket, and the backend is a ZMQ_DEALER socket, the proxy shall act as a shared queue that collects requests from a set of clients, and distributes these fairly among a set of services. Requests shall be fair-queued from frontend connections and distributed evenly across backend connections. Replies shall automatically return to the client that made the original request.

The proxy handles multiple clients and and uses multiple workers to process the requests. The identity is used to send the response to the right client. You cannot use the identify to "select" a specific worker.